# Trying to compile ZeroMQ, czmq yields undefined: zmq_poller_new for Raspberry Pi

Tags: zeromq, failed-installation

```
System: Raspberry Pi 3
OS: "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
ZeroMQ /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5.1.3 /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
```

I'm trying to install czmq-4.0.2

When I get to the "**`make check`**" step, it grinds away and dies at:

> `czmq-4.0.2/src/.libs/lt-czmq_selftest: symbol lookup error: /home/pi/Downloads/czmq-4.0.2/src/.libs/libczmq.so.4: undefined symbol: zmq_poller_new`
>   `Makefile:1829: recipe for target 'check-local' failed`
>   `make[2]: *** [check-local] Error 127`

`zmq_poller_new` seems to live in the `src/.libs/libczmq.so.4` lib it was building:

```
strings /home/pi/PyVirtualEnv/libzmq/czmq/src/.libs/libczmq.so.4 | grep zmq_poller_new
zmq_poller_new
zmq_poller_new
zmq_poller_new
```

Is this a build error? Or something I've omitted?

I've tried this from both github and tar file downloads, 
but am getting the same error at the same place. The net
doesn't seem to have this problem, so I guess this is
something I'm doing.

Comment: Are you building this inside the raspberry?

Comment: Yes, I'm building on the raspberry. Since this is a debian based system, this should be OK? I wasn't aware binaries were available. Even if binaries were avail, a compile from source should be ok, right?

Comment: If you weren't then you would be doing cross compile, which is another wild beast. `zmq_poller_new` symbol is missing. Try to find it on the sources or use readelf, or objdump to search it on binaries. This kind of error usually mean something was compiled wrong,